# Inserting User Input Values into a Function

Tags: javascript, html, variables, user-input

I am trying to take a user input value that is entered through an html input box, and have it as a value within my function (the negKeyword function in my code to be more specific). The problem that I think is happening is this input value is stored as a variable, so when the code is first stored in memory it is stored as "", since the user has not inputed anything yet. How do I get it so when the user inputs something it replaces blank or "" with what ever the user inputs?

What I basically want to happen next is the user will click a button, it will then compare what the user inputs to what the "negKeyword" function outputs and give a result on whether they match or not (this action is demonstrated in my booleanKeyword function in my code).

Here is my code.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var arr = ['no', 'not', 'checked']; 
var text = ''; //JS output variable.
var keyword = 'leak'; //Individual keyword.

function negKeyword() {
  
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
 if (text == input) { break; } 
 text = arr[i] + ' ' + keyword;
 
 }
 return text;
}
 
function booleanKeyword() { 

 if (input == negKeyword()) { 
  
  document.getElementById("result").style.color="green";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Match";
 
 } else {
 
  document.getElementById("result").style.color="red";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="No Match";
 
 }
 
}

document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML=keyword;
```

```html
<label for="Full Negative Keyword">Negative Keyword</label> <input id="input" type="text" />

<div id="message">Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
<div id="message">Keyword: <span id="result2"></span></div>
        
        <button id="test" onclick="booleanKeyword()">Click to Test</button>
```

Comment: Hi you wanna that when is clicked it will reset the input value ?

Comment: Basically yes, that was the user input can be used in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the input's value again, by getting it and assigning to the same variable (but inside the function that is called after the button click).

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
var arr = ['no', 'not', 'checked']; 
var text = ''; //JS output variable.
var keyword = 'leak'; //Individual keyword.

function negKeyword() {

  input = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
 if (text == input) { break; } 
 text = arr[i] + ' ' + keyword;
 
 }
 return text;
}
 
function booleanKeyword() { 

        input = document.getElementById("input").value;//The variable is reassigned, only after the click

 if (input == negKeyword()) { 
  
  document.getElementById("result").style.color="green";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Match";
 
 } else {
 
  document.getElementById("result").style.color="red";
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="No Match";
 
 }
 
}

document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML=keyword;
```

Edit: added the same code to `negKeyword()` function as it requires the input too.

Comment: Not the nicest solution though, instead of rereading the input value from the DOM, you should use the `this` object in the event listener and pass its value on to any functions that need it (as parameters).

Comment: True, I just wanted to change the code as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because your variable input is always "". You have to assign new value to it each time the button is clicked. I just moved your code for input in BooleanKeyword() function. Now everything is working fine.

Everytime when something like this is not working, just try to log/alert values.

For example you could just alert(input + ' ' + negKeyword()); on top of booleanKeyword() function and you would see problem by yourself.

```js
var input;
var arr = ['no', 'not', 'checked']; 
var text = ''; //JS output variable.
var keyword = 'leak'; //Individual keyword.

function negKeyword() {
        
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    
    if (text == input) { break; }   
    text = arr[i] + ' ' + keyword;
    
    }
    return text;
}
    
function booleanKeyword() { 
    input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if (input == negKeyword()) { 
        
        document.getElementById("result").style.color="green";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Match";
    
    } else {
    
        document.getElementById("result").style.color="red";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="No Match";
    
    }
    
}

document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML=keyword;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 </head>
<body>
<label for="Full Negative Keyword">Negative Keyword</label> <input id="input" type="text" />

<div id="message">Result: <span id="result"></span></div>
<div id="message">Keyword: <span id="result2"></span></div>
        
        <button id="test" onclick="booleanKeyword()">Click to Test</button>

</html>
```